# UITableViewCell nib with several constraint scenarios

Tags: cocoa-touch, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, nib

I have a UITableViewCell nib that depending on the data it can show an image or not.

Below, the cell has 2 labels and at the right most the imageView. What I want to do is to remove the imageView (if no image is present on the data) and extend the Label all the way to the right.

Is there a way to have several constraint scenarios on the nib that I could activate/ deactivate?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraints on **label1**

1. **leading**, 2. **center vertically in container**, 3. **fixed width**

Constraints on **label2**

1. **Leading space** with `label1`,  2. **Center vertically in Container**

Constraints on **imageview**

1. **Trailing space**, 2. **Top space**, 3. **Bottom space**,
2. **Width constraint** : width <= 50 (When there is no image then width will automatically get zero),
3. Horizontal space between

   **label2** and **imageview** = 0 (priority = 250)

See the below GIF:

[image]